# Android bound service without IPC

Tags: android, android-service

I want to bind my activity to a service that is supposed to die as soon as the activity itself dies. After googling, I found out that bound services are used for this. However, bound services also come with the big and confusing burden of creating binders and service connections which I believe is used for IPC.
My service is completely isolated and does not need to communicate anything with the calling activity. So how do I bind to the service without using any of the IPC features? All I want is for my service to get automatically destroyed if there are no clients connected to it.